# Read multiple non-sequential images from multiple folders

Tags: matlab

I have a folder (new_images) which contains 52 sub-folders (person1 to person52) and each sub-folders contain 50 images which are not sequential (like: person1 1, person1 3, person1 10). I want to these read images from each sub-folders and do a processing, How can I do this?

I would really appreciate your answers

Comment: doc `dir()`. Plenty of solutions here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load images using the Matlab `imread` function.

I'm thinking of a quick way to do that:

```
new_images_rep = pwd;
for i=1:52
    eval(srcat('pics = dir(new_images_rep','/person',num2str(i),')');
    for k=1:50
        a(i,k) = imread(pics(k+2).name,'fmt'); %there is k+2 because the dir function also stores repositories like '.' or '..'.
    end
end
```

You have to be careful with the `dir` function. You should test it in your `new_images`  repository in order to see what are the files/repositories stored in `pics`.

`eval` is a Matlab function that allows you to execute any Matlab expression. The string created by `strcat`is here (if `i=3`):

```
'pics = dir(new_images_rep/person3)'
```

Be sure that the `new_images`repository is in your Matlab path, or replace `new_images_rep = pwd;` by `new_images_rep = 'the_actual_full_path'`.

`'fmt'` is the actual format of the images you want to store (like `.tif` or `.jpg` or anything else).

Using the code I gave you (and a few modifications), all the files from the first subfolder will be stored in `a(1,:)`. Do not hesitate to read Matlab help on every function used here.